# Powershell Assign MobilePhone property from Active Directory to variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a small script I wrote but I am wondering if this is the correct way to pull the `MobilePhone` property from Active Directory using powershell?

```
$csvfi = import-csv "C:\Users\\Documents\users.csv"

foreach($row in $csvfi)
{
    $cellphone = $row.Phone
    $fullname = $row.Name

    $adphone = (Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$fullname'" -Properties * | Select MobilePhone).MobilePhone

    Write-Host $fullname, $adphone
}
```

It just seems cumbersome to do `-Filter`, then `-Properties *`, then pipe to `Select` and then get the `.MobilePhone` attribute from that object.

As a side note, I just need the raw Mobile Phone number from AD, 1-AAA-NNN-NNNN so I can compare it with the cell phone number in the spread sheet `users.csv`.

Comment: what's your definition of correct? this seems to work. what else do you expect? why don't you want to do `-properties MobilePhone`?

Comment: guess shorter. or is going through all the options i mentioned above the only way? it just seems like alot just to extract 1 property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$adphone = (Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$fullname'" -Properties MobilePhone).MobilePhone
```

Comment: This actually works also `(Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$fullname'" -Properties *).MobilePhone` but I assume its less efficient since it pulls in all the properties? Bascially using `*` is just to visually see all the properties for that object, and if you know the property name then just use it explicitly?

Comment: Correct, unless you need all properties for some reason obviously. You can also exclude -properties altogether and get a default set of properties but that doesn't include mobile phone afaik.

Comment: No it does not. It gives you SamAccountName and basic properties like that. Thanks